# SQL Server Multiple Sorting Clarification

Tags: sql-server, sorting

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY C_CallID ORDER BY DATETIME) ROWNUMBER
    ,CallID
    ,C_CALLID
    ,NAME
    ,DATETIME
FROM
    TABLENAME
ORDER BY DATETIME
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY C_CallID ORDER BY DATETIME, ASC NAME DESC) ROWNUMBER
    ,CallID
    ,C_CALLID
    ,NAME
    ,DATETIME
FROM
    TABLENAME
ORDER BY DATETIME ASC, NAME DESC
```

**Query 1 Output:**

[image]

**Query 2 Output:**

[image]

So my understanding is Rownumber will be sorting based on `DATETIME` `ASC` for all the records and then Sorting will be `DESC` for `NAME` column records.

My question here is "Will second sorting affects first sorted data in anyway?"

Comment: No, it will not. The sequence of sort works that way, it will sort by 1st column and if 1st column has same data then it will go to 2nd sort column and so on.

Comment: Side note, that second query will error, as you are missing a comma (`,`) between your 2 sort declarations in the `ORDER BY` (in both the `OVER` clause *and* the "main" query's `ORDER BY`).

Comment: @Larnu Agreed. Thanks for highlighting. So the answer is "Already First Sorted record will not get impacted and the second sorting will only happen for the same data with first sorted data?"

Comment: Think of each clause as a "tie breaker". The data is sorted by the first clause, then the 2nd clause is a "tie breaker" for when 2 (or more) rows have the same value. If there is a 3rd clause, then that's the "tie breaker" for when the rows have the same value for *both* the prior clauses, etc, etc. Just like with a phone book; it's ordered by Surname first, and then  the first initial (if known); the initial is the "tie breaker".

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for the example. It make sense to me now while visualizing your example,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always easier to explain using a simple example.
consider the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE Sample (
  A int,
  B int
);

INSERT INTO Sample (A, B) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(1, 3),
(2, 1),
(3, 1),
(3, 2),
(3, 3);
```

And the following queries:

```
SELECT A, B
FROM Sample
ORDER BY A ASC, B ASC;

A   B
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   1
3   1
3   2
3   3


SELECT A, B
FROM Sample
ORDER BY A ASC, B DESC;

A   B
1   3
1   2
1   1
2   1
3   3
3   2
3   1
```

Both queries will result with A in ascending order, but the first will have B in ascending order as well, while the second with have B in descending order - So the second sort does not affect the first one in any way.
The secondary sort only kicks in when the primary sort returns multiple rows with equal values in that column.
Of course, that rule applies even if you have an order by clause that contains more than two columns.